# Implementing 3rd party .js file in react JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, script-tag

I am having issue in calling a 3rd party javascript in my react project.

i called like this in index.html file inside body tag

```
    <body>
     <script src="https://zwibbler.com/zwibbler-demo.js"></script>
    </body
```

i also called the script in `<head>` tag but that also didn't work.

i am being able to fetch and use it successfully in my fresh create-react-app but when i integrate it to my existing react project the script shows it loaded in network tab but does not render the output. what should i do to load it?

i also called script in `componentDidMount` like below but that doesn't work.

used in `componentDidMount`:

```
   componentDidMount(){
      const script  = document.createElement("script");
      script.src = "https://zwibbler.com/zwibbler-demo.js";
      document.body.appendChild(script);
   }
```

The component in which i am using it (3rd party lib) comes after two or three routes later, means user has to do some action/events to get to render that component, so is it due to these event that i can not use the liberary? or simply how do i call that script when the component loads ? i have already tried `componentWill/DidMount()`.

Comment: add this file in index.html

Comment: @SalmanArshad which file?

Comment: Include script `"https://zwibbler.com/zwibbler-demo.js` in index.js

Comment: @SalmanArshad please share a sample, that will be awesome.

Answer (score 1):

i got the solution, thanks everyone for helping and supporting
the solution was i need not to worry about the script being loaded, i have to just call a script in `index.html` and then i wrote my component like this

```
class ZwibblerComponent extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                Some sample buttons<br />
                <button onClick={() => this.ctx.useBrushTool()}>Brush</button>
                <button onClick={() => this.ctx.download("zwibbler3", "drawing.zwibbler")}>Save to computer</button>
                <button onClick={() => this.ctx.openFromComputer()}>Open from computer</button>

                <div ref={el => this.el = el}
                    style={{ width: "500px", height: "500px" }}>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.ctx = Zwibbler.create(this.el, {
            setFocus: false,
            showToolbar: false,
        })
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        this.ctx.destroy();
        console.log("Destroying");
    }

}
```

ahh... finally its solved, if any one is looking for zwibbler implmentation in react.js... its here folks.

Comment: can you let me know i can set the background Image for my zwibbler

Comment: @NarendraChouhan there is the property defined in Zwibbler as "backgroundImage" in Zwibbler's documentation "https://www.zwibbler.com/docs" ,  but if you want to set it on an action you have to do it by vanilla javascript like find the node first then style the image to width, height as '100%'